# Making listview expandable vertically

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have divided my xaml page in 3 column. The last column has a list-view and now I'm adding a property grid underneath of it. How can I add a feature on UI such that would allow user to resize the listview or property grid vertically? 
I tried  but either I'm using wrong attribute or it is not meant for this reason. any help will be appreciated.

```
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="5" Background="gray">

        **<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >**
        <ListView Background="LightGray" Opacity="1" ForceCursor="False" x:Name="myListView" x:FieldModifier="public" Height="326" >
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Parts List" Width="80"/>
                 </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        **</ScrollViewer>**

        <DockPanel>
            <Grid>
                <wpg:WpfPropertyGrid x:Name="PropertyGrid1" 

                VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HelpVisible="{Binding ElementName=ShowDescrip, Path=IsChecked}" 
                ToolbarVisible="{Binding ElementName=ShowToolbar, Path=IsChecked}"
                PropertySort="{Binding ElementName=ComboSort, Path=SelectedItem}" />
            </Grid>
        </DockPanel>
    </StackPanel>
```

Thanks.
Amit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably use a `Grid` and a `GridSplitter`.
You can [have a look here](http://wpftutorial.net/GridLayout.html#resize) for a quick example.

Comment: I'm sure it is my fault and this is what happening now: both are placed inside a grid as you suggested.
Wihtout Grid look fine but again it doesn't let user to resize neither treeview nor property gird and using grid it replaces property-grid over treeview.